# Is PrEP used for anything other than HIV?

Tags: microbiology, pharmacology, virology, infectious-diseases

In the field of HIV prevention, PrEP is an abbreviation of *pre-exposure prophylaxis*. This is a very generic term. Are any diseases other than HIV prevented using a similar approach? Do they use the same name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prophylaxis is typically prior to exposure. [Condoms](https://www.cdc.gov/condomeffectiveness/index.html), for example, were historically referred to as [prophylactics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_condoms), in that they prevent pregnancy and many STIs. The reason the *pre-exposure* bit is given special attention in this context is that it refers to use of drugs with substantial risk of harm. Because of their associated risk, these drugs were previously only used for [post exposure prophylaxis](https://www.cdc.gov/hiv/basics/pep.html). Similar to rabies vaccination after an animal bite, this strategy involves preventative treatment given after exposure but before a critical point in the progress of an infection.

To more directly answer your questions

> Are any diseases other than HIV prevented using pre-exposure prophylaxis?

Many, many, many diseases. [Vaccines](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/pubs/pinkbook/index.html) are a good example of prophylactic treatment, typically given prior to exposure. [Malaria prophylaxis](https://www.cdc.gov/malaria/travelers/drugs.html) is another example, where a medication (with non insignificant risk of harm) is given to healthy people traveling to an endemic area.

> Do they use a different term?

In most cases, as you can see by searching for the words used in the linked references, the term is simply *prophylaxis*, rather than *pre-exposure prophylaxis*.

Comment: Yes, I'd wondered about the semantics. I assume vaccines aren't classed as _PrEP_ because of the different mechanism by which they work?

Comment: @ChrisW vaccines are treatment prior to exposure, intended to prevent infection. And so they *are* pre exposure prophylaxis*, but they are typically just referred to as **prophylaxis**. The special terminology for HIV PrEP is, as I indicated, to distinguish use of ARV prior to exposure from use of ARV **post exposure**, which has been done for about 25 years.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the difference in that vaccines are typically an injection *of* the virus, (immune response) rather than a continual drug to prevent the disease if you come into contact with it (pharmacological response) - I hadn't realised that both were technically PrEP.

Comment: @ChrisW condoms are technically pre-exposure prophylaxis as well.